# Insert image into SQL database

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that lists details of place (name, address etc) of places and I also want to have an image of the place. I was wondering if anyone knew of an easy way to upload images into a SQL Database?

Comment: Please be more relevant, which database are you using ?

Comment: @UmeshABhat - The question is tagged tsql, meaning SQL Server, most likely.

Comment: something like this?? http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2007/09/26/Insert-binary-data-like-images-into-SQL-Server-without-front-end.aspx

Comment: @RobertRozas wy not put that as an answer, seems like it will do the job

Comment: Okey....i'll post my answer ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow this example :

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(Document varbinary(max))
INSERT INTO myTable(Document)
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Image1.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) rs
```

PS: Instead of varbinary(max) you can put your defined max value for the varbinary file.

Edited: I add just an alias rs at the end of the script.

Saludos ;)

Comment: Thanks Robert, I will try that now. But where you have put N'C:\Image1.jpg' do I replace it with the location of my picture?

Comment: I get the following error message: 

Msg 491, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
A correlation name must be specified for the bulk rowset in the from clause.

Comment: I'm editing....wait a bit xD

Comment: That has worked great, thank you. But what if I want to insert into a pre excisting table?

Comment: Then you dont have to create the table...just make the insert to your specific table from your database ;)

Comment: Morning Robert, it doesn't seem to be working, can you help. My SQL below.

USE RACING INSERT INTO Racetracks(RaceTrackPicture) SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pictures for Database\Racecourses\Cheltenham-Racecourse.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) rs WHERE RaceTrackID = '1';

Comment: instead of insert you should try update.....when you do an insert its supose that record dont exist...and because of that, insert with a where is wtf xD....if the record exist you can try an update instead an insert ;)

Comment: One I think is missing in the above discussion is that the file path needs to be as seen from the SQL Server, not the client that is running SQL Management Studio.  So, I had to PUT THE FILE ON THE FILESYSTEM OF THE SERVER FIRST before executing this statement.  Kind of reduces the usefulness of this method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just upload the images to a webspace and have the name of the image (which in turn will be the exact URI) in a SQL database?

If you have a schema column with mountRushmore.png and your images are uploaded to mywebsite.com/images/, then you know the exact URI is mywebsite.com/images/mountRushmore.png.

Do you need the database for something else? There are easier way to store data being accessed by a website then a database. Namely XML or JSON.

I hope this helps.

Comment: while its likely that wafw1971 is developing a web application they have not explicitly stated this. what if they are developing something for the desktop? their question is valid although not very well researched.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what any of what has been said is, I just thought it would be a simple Insert statement, taking a picture from the c:drive and putting it in the database.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure why I assumed it was a web application, I guess I just have Web App on the mind.